# Optimize SQL Scheduler for inserting data from select statement

Tags: sql-server-2008, query-optimization

anyone know how to optimize SQL query for inserting data from select statement and so the log file won't grow too fast? I tried WITH (NOLOCK) already. It works but the log file grow quite fast.

Currently I have SQL Scheduler to move the data from one database to another database under the same server and the same instance.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE Mobile.dbo.[Customer] 

INSERT INTO Mobile.dbo.[Customer]
SELECT
    CST.[No], CST.[Name], CST.[Address], CST.[Address 2], CST.[Post Code], CST.[City], CST.[County] AS [State], 
    CST.[Country_Region Code] AS [Country Code], CST.[Contact], CST.[Phone No_], CST.[Fax No_], CST.[Telex No_] AS [Mobile No_],
    CST.[E-Mail], CST.[Home Page], CAST(CST.[Credit Limit] AS DECIMAL (38,2)) AS [Credit Limit], 
    CASE 
        WHEN (CAST(INV.[Amount] AS DECIMAL) IS NOT NULL) THEN CAST((INV.[Amount]) AS DECIMAL (38,2))
        ELSE '0.00'
    END AS [Balance],
    CST.[Salesperson Code], CST.[Payment Terms], CST.[Payment Code], CST.Zone Code]
FROM Live.dbo.[Customer] AS CST
WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT ORIamt.[Customer No_], SUM(ORIamt.[Amount]) AS [Amount]
    FROM (
        SELECT CLE.[Entry No_], CLE.[Customer No_], CLE.[Document No_], DCLE.[Amount]
        FROM Live.dbo.[Entry] AS CLE
        WITH (NOLOCK)
        LEFT JOIN(
            SELECT [Cust_ Entry No_], SUM([Amount]) AS [Amount]
            FROM Live.dbo.[Detailed Entry]
            WITH (NOLOCK)
            GROUP BY [Cust_ Entry No_]
        ) DCLE ON CLE.[Entry No_] = DCLE.[Cust_ Entry No_]
    ) AS ORIamt
    GROUP BY ORIamt.[Customer No_]
) AS INV ON INV.[Customer No_] = CST.[No_]
```

As you all can see, I have one database named Mobile. And Actually this database is used for showing the data only. Since this database is for showing the data only, I wonder how to optimize my SQL Scheduler and so the log file won't grow too fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're truncating `Mobile.dbo.Customer`, and Mobile is in Simple recovery mode, would it be feasible instead to drop `Mobile.dbo.Customer` and then recreate it with `Select..into Mobile.dbo.Customer..`, instead of `insert into`? That approach should provide the minimal logging you need.

Comment: Hi John thanks for your response. I set the recovery mode to simple already. May I know which one is better between recovery bulk_logged and simple?

Comment: They both perform minimal logging. So in this case a recovery mode switch to bulk_logged won't matter. But, since you're truncating `Mobile.dbo.Customer`, would it be feasible instead to drop `Mobile.dbo.Customer` and then recreate it with `Select..into Mobile.dbo.Customer..`, instead of `insert into`? That approach should provide the minimal logging you need.

Comment: Hi John, Yes I think your suggestion is good to me. Thanks John.

Comment: You're welcome:) I updated the answer to reflect this approach.